# args and kwargs in django views

Tags: python, django, django-views, args, keyword-argument

Okay, I've tried searching for this for quite some time. Can I not pass args and kwargs to a view in a django app? Do I necessarily have to define each keyword argument independently?

For example,

```
#views.py
def someview(request, *args, **kwargs):
...
```

And while calling the view,

```
response = someview(request,locals())
```

I can't seem to be able to do that. 
Instead, I have to do:

```
#views.py
def someview(request, somekey = None):
...
```

Any reasons why?

Comment: *args and **kwargs are not mandatory in each of your views, the request object is

Comment: I'm sorry, that's not what I was looking for. I've edited the question. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: what is the result you are seeing? an error message?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If it's keyword arguments you want to pass into your view, the proper syntax is:

```
def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

my_kwargs = dict(
    hello='world',
    star='wars'
)

response = view(request, **my_kwargs)
```

thus, if `locals()` are keyword arguments, you pass in `**locals()`. I personally wouldn't use something implicit like `locals()`

Answer (score 6):

*args and **kwargs are used to pass a variable number of arguments to a function. Single asterisk is used for non-keyworded arguments and double for keyworded argument.

For example:

```
    def any_funtion(*args, **kwargs):
         //some code

    any_function(1,arg1="hey",arg2="bro")
```

In this, the first one is a simple (non-keyworded) argument and the other two are keyworded arguments;

Comment: Hey Rishi! Could you use code formatting in your answer to make it more readable? Just put three ` symbols and three ` symbols after your code! :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `locals()` returns a dictionary. If you want to use `**kwargs` you will need to unpack `locals`:

```
response = someview(request,**locals())
```

When you use it like `response = someview(request,locals())` you are in fact passing a dictionary as an argument:

```
response = someview(request, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, ..})
```

But when you use `**locals()` you are using it like this:

```
response = someview(request, a=1, b=2, ..})
```

You might want to take a look at [Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)